# Azure ARM template - nested resource reference

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to configure an Azure SQL database for multi-region replication and I am having a hard time to reference the source database in my ARM template.

```
  "outputs": {
"primarySQL": {
  "type": "object",
  "value": "[reference(concat(parameters('serverNamePrimary')))]"
},
"primaryDB": {
  "type": "object",
  "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases','/',parameters('serverNamePrimary'),'/',parameters('databaseName')))]"
}
}
```

The reference to the SQL Server works fine. 
The reference to the database doesn't work.

How do I get the resourceId from a database that I am deploying in the same template?
I need to use the db's resourceId later then to reference that as the `sourceDatabaseId` as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/databases

Cheers
David

Answer (score 1):

Never mind... seems you can't reference this in the `Outputs` section...
but adding this here to the secondary DB resource works:

`"sourceDatabaseId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', parameters('serverNamePrimary'), parameters('databaseName'))]",`